# Amending VBA to loop over a known list of servers

Tags: excel, vba

I found some VBA code to do nslookup against IP Addresses in Excel. The site is owned by [@svish](https://stackoverflow.com/users/39321/svish) and the full code is here https://www.geekality.net/2016/03/07/excel-function-for-nslookup-in-worksheet/

It is a VBA function to do an nslookup against an IP address contained in a cell using the format `=nslookup(cell_reference,response_type)` where response is either Hostname or IP Address referenced by the integers 2 and 1 respectively. An example formula in Excel might be `=nslookup(a1,2)` to return the hostname of the IP address contained in cell A1

This snippet seems to be the section that does the lookup and processes the output.

```
    'Run the nslookup command
    sFilename = oFSO.GetTempName
    oShell.Run "cmd /c nslookup " & lookupVal & " > " & sFilename, 0, True
    Set oTempFile = oFSO.OpenTextFile(sFilename, 1)
    Do While oTempFile.AtEndOfStream <> True
        sLine = oTempFile.Readline
        cmdStr = cmdStr & Trim(sLine) & vbCrLf
    Loop
    oTempFile.Close
    oFSO.DeleteFile (sFilename)
   
    'Process the result
    intFound = InStr(1, cmdStr, "Name:", vbTextCompare)
    If intFound = 0 Then
        NSLookup = ""
        Exit Function
    ElseIf intFound > 0 Then
        'TODO: Cleanup with RegEx
        If addressOpt = ADDRESS_LOOKUP Then
            loc1 = InStr(intFound, cmdStr, "Address:", vbTextCompare) + InStr(intFound, cmdStr, "Addresses:", vbTextCompare)
            loc2 = InStr(loc1, cmdStr, vbCrLf, vbTextCompare)
            nameStr = Trim(Mid(cmdStr, loc1 + 8, loc2 - loc1 - 8))
        ElseIf addressOpt = NAME_LOOKUP Then
            loc1 = InStr(intFound, cmdStr, "Name:", vbTextCompare)
            loc2 = InStr(loc1, cmdStr, vbCrLf, vbTextCompare)
            nameStr = Trim(Mid(cmdStr, loc1 + 5, loc2 - loc1 - 5))
        End If
    End If
    NSLookup = nameStr
Else
    NSLookup = "N/A"
End If
```

I need to be able to iterate over a predetermined list of DNS servers, pass the name of the server to the nslookup command as a paremter like this `nslookup IP_To_Resolve DNSServer` then check to see if the output is valid and try the next server if it is not

I don't know enough VBA to read this code and know where to place the loop. Any suggestions or pointers would be appreciated.

---

So I have had a go at this and made the following changes

Amending the line

```
oShell.Run "cmd /c nslookup " & lookupVal & " > " & sFilename, 0, True
```

To read

```
oShell.Run "cmd /c nslookup " & lookupVal & " ns1.domain1.com" & " > " & sFilename, 0, True
```

gives the required result for running the query against an alternate name server

Armed with this information and google I attempted the following changes:

declare an array at the very start of the function

```
static Nameservers as String
Nameserver = Array("ns1.domain1.com",ns1.domain2.com",ns1.domain3.com")
```

Then I added a for loop and an if statement to check if it had found a result

```
'Run the nslookup command
For i = 1 To 3
    sFilename = oFSO.GetTempName
    oShell.Run "cmd /c nslookup " & lookupVal & " " & NameServers(i) & " > " & sFilename, 0, True
    Set oTempFile = oFSO.OpenTextFile(sFilename, 1)
    Do While oTempFile.AtEndOfStream <> True
        sLine = oTempFile.Readline
        cmdStr = cmdStr & Trim(sLine) & vbCrLf
    Loop
    oTempFile.Close
    oFSO.DeleteFile (sFilename)
    intFound = InStr(1, cmdStr, "Name:", vbTextCompare)
    If intFound <> 0 Then
        Exit For
    End If
Next i
```

Unfortunately I get an error

> Compile Error: Expected Array

on this line  `oShell.Run "cmd /c nslookup " & lookupVal & " " & NameServers(i) & " > " & sFilename, 0, True` highlighting the `NameServers(i)`

what have I done wrong?

Comment: Not clear what you want accomplishing. So, you wan iterating between a list of DNS servers. Where from to take `response_type` and where to return the function result?

Comment: yes; I need to try several different name servers with the nslookup command. `nslookup 10.10.10.1 ns1.domain.com` then try `nslookup 10.10.10.1 ns1.domain2.com` if the IP doesn't resolve. I have several reports for different domains all with their own name servers. Each domain uses different (multiple) subnets so there wont be any duplication.

Answer (score 1):

With some trial and error I got this to work by making the following amendments.

Added an array of nameservers at the start

```
NameServers = Array("ns1.domain1.com" _
   "ns1.domain2.com", _
   "ns1.domain3.com", _
   "ns1.domain4.com", _
   "ns1.domain5.com", _
   "ns1.domain6.com", _
   "ns1.domain7.com")
```

Added a for loop

```
'Run the nslookup command
For i = 1 To 3
    sFilename = oFSO.GetTempName
    oShell.Run "cmd /c nslookup " & lookupVal & " " & NameServers(i) & " > " & sFilename, 0, True
    Set oTempFile = oFSO.OpenTextFile(sFilename, 1)
    Do While oTempFile.AtEndOfStream <> True
        sLine = oTempFile.Readline
        cmdStr = cmdStr & Trim(sLine) & vbCrLf
    Loop
    oTempFile.Close
    oFSO.DeleteFile (sFilename)
    intFound = InStr(1, cmdStr, "Name:", vbTextCompare)
    If intFound <> 0 Then
        Exit For
    End If
Next i
```

Added NameServers(i) as a parameter that is sent to cmd as part of the command

```
oShell.Run "cmd /c nslookup " & lookupVal & " " & NameServers(i) & " > " & sFilename, 0, True
```

The complete code that I now have working (albeit a bit slow) is:

```
Public Function NSLookup(lookupVal As String, Optional addressOpt As Integer) As String
   Const ADDRESS_LOOKUP = 1
   Const NAME_LOOKUP = 2
   Const AUTO_DETECT = 0
   NameServers = Array("ns1.domain1.com" _
       "ns1.domain2.com", _
       "ns1.domain3.com", _
       "ns1.domain4.com", _
       "ns1.domain5.com", _
       "ns1.domain6.com", _
       "ns1.domain7.com")

   'Skip everything if the field is blank
   If lookupVal <> "" Then
        Dim oFSO As Object, oShell As Object, oTempFile As Object
        Dim sLine As String, sFilename As String
        Dim intFound As Integer
        Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        Set oShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
       
        'Handle the addresOpt operand
        'Regular Expressions are used to complete a substring match for an IP Address
        'If an IP Address is found, a DNS Name Lookup will be forced
        If addressOpt = AUTO_DETECT Then
            ipLookup = FindIP(lookupVal)
            If ipLookup = "" Then
                addressOpt = ADDRESS_LOOKUP
            Else
                addressOpt = NAME_LOOKUP
                lookupVal = ipLookup
            End If
        'Do a regular expression substring match for an IP Address
        ElseIf addressOpt = NAME_LOOKUP Then
            lookupVal = FindIP(lookupVal)
        End If
       
        'Run the nslookup command
        For i = 1 To 7
            sFilename = oFSO.GetTempName
            oShell.Run "cmd /c nslookup " & lookupVal & " " & NameServers(i) & " > " & sFilename, 0, True
            Set oTempFile = oFSO.OpenTextFile(sFilename, 1)
            Do While oTempFile.AtEndOfStream <> True
                sLine = oTempFile.Readline
                cmdStr = cmdStr & Trim(sLine) & vbCrLf
            Loop
            oTempFile.Close
            oFSO.DeleteFile (sFilename)
            intFound = InStr(1, cmdStr, "Name:", vbTextCompare)
            If intFound <> 0 Then
                Exit For
            End If
        Next i
            
        
        'Process the result
        intFound = InStr(1, cmdStr, "Name:", vbTextCompare)
        If intFound = 0 Then
            NSLookup = "Not Found"
            Exit Function
        ElseIf intFound > 0 Then
            'TODO: Cleanup with RegEx
            If addressOpt = ADDRESS_LOOKUP Then
                loc1 = InStr(intFound, cmdStr, "Address:", vbTextCompare) + InStr(intFound, cmdStr, "Addresses:", vbTextCompare)
                loc2 = InStr(loc1, cmdStr, vbCrLf, vbTextCompare)
                nameStr = Trim(Mid(cmdStr, loc1 + 8, loc2 - loc1 - 8))
            ElseIf addressOpt = NAME_LOOKUP Then
                loc1 = InStr(intFound, cmdStr, "Name:", vbTextCompare)
                loc2 = InStr(loc1, cmdStr, vbCrLf, vbTextCompare)
                nameStr = Trim(Mid(cmdStr, loc1 + 5, loc2 - loc1 - 5))
            End If
        End If
        NSLookup = nameStr
    Else
        NSLookup = "N/A"
    End If
End Function

Function FindIP(strTest As String) As String
    Dim RegEx As Object
    Dim valid As Boolean
    Dim Matches As Object
    Dim i As Integer
    Set RegEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
   
    RegEx.Pattern = "\b(?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}\b"
    valid = RegEx.test(strTest)
    If valid Then
        Set Matches = RegEx.Execute(strTest)
        FindIP = Matches(0)
    Else
        FindIP = ""
    End If
End Function
```

It isn't quick and took about a minute to do 100 IP addresses. I am pretty certain it could be made more efficient but for now it works.

Comment: added to my git if anyone wants to pull the code